# Missing .aspx extension in Insert Link url (Sitecore 8.2)

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.2

When inserting a Sitecore Item using Insert Link in a Field Name, the .aspx extension of the inserted url is not showing. The current version im using is Sitecore 8.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Sitecore 8.2 this is the default behavior due to the configuration of the LinkProvider.

```xml
<linkManager defaultProvider="sitecore">
   <providers>
     <clear />
     <add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" 
         addAspxExtension="false" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false" encodeNames="true" languageEmbedding="asNeeded" 
         languageLocation="filePath" lowercaseUrls="false" shortenUrls="true" useDisplayName="false" />
   </providers>
</linkManager>
```

The addAspxExtension attribute is set to a value of false and that instructs Sitecore to not include the .aspx extension in rendered hyperlink URLs.